# Problems running app when signed

Tags: java, midp

When I sign my jar file using jad tool and try to run on a phone I get the error message - 'Invalid File'

Any ideas what could be wrong ?

Has anyone had problems signing midlet jar files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REMVOED JAD-MIDLIET-1 from jad descriptor